# CRF++/Wapiti include category of entire sentence as feature

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition, crf, crf++

How can I represent category of sentence predicted from Naive Bayes as a feature in CRF++ or Wapiti?

For instance, if the sentence, `Tumblr merges with Yahoo.`, is classified as `Business`, then while composing the training file for crf, where can I indicate the label `Business` as a feature? And how should then the template be modeled?

Should the train file be like this

```
Tumblr    business    ORG
merges    business    O
with     business    O
Yahoo    business    ORG
```

Or only include the category with the `ORG` label? How so? And the template file?

Answer (score 2):

Method 1: 
You can add `business` as a feature in the same way you have shown or you can simply write `1` instead of `business`. Similarly, for category `sports` you can add another column and the value in this column shall be `1` for words belonging to sports sentence.
You'll have to add each column in the template file too, respectively.

```
U42:%x[0,1] #for business
U43:%x[0,2] #for sports
```

Method 2:
Including category with ORG might not be a good idea because the same ORG can appear in different categories.

Comment: The concern I see for Method 1 is, general words will get that category label as well. Those general words  can appear in a different structure in some other sentence. Don't you think this would dilute the importance of the category. 
Because if you think about it, certain entities have a higher chance to appear in a sentence of a particular category. 

Personally I would prefer Method 2 with the addition of making context of words for the category marked in the template, `U42:%x[0,1]/%x[-1,0]/%x[0,0]/%x[1,0]` and so forth. 

Is it right in a sense?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know your train file is the only way to include sentence-level annotation, unless you'd consider adapting / implementing a CRF that takes into account sentence-level features.

If you have enough training data and a limited number of categories, this method would probably affect a low weight to sentence categories: it would only be used to distinguish named entities whenever they are ambiguous and when the computed NE categories probabilities are somehow close.

Best way would indeed be to train with/without this feature and see if it improves NER! Should be an interesting experimentation :)